# Difference in usage between the nouns "merge" and "merger"

Tags: word-usage

As a non-native speaker I am having some trouble distinguishing between the two words "merge" and "merger". To me, it sounds like "merger" describes a major event, often occurring between legal entities such as companies, countries, pieces of industry,... In computer science, I have more often seen merge used as a noun, e.g. if in a version control system two branches are merged, the result is called a merge. The process while it is occurring is also called a merge.

Are the two terms interchangeable, or are there clear distinctions in usage (in general practice)?

Comment: Merge is to combine or join. Merger is the act of merging or the state of being merged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In everyday use, *merge* is not used as a noun. You can see this in the following [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=merge_VERB%2Cmerger_NOUN%2Cmerge_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmerge_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmerger_NOUN%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Merge (verb), Merger (noun), Merge (noun) Google ngram]

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/merge?q=merge), [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merge) and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/merge?s=t) have yet to record it as a noun, if they ever will. As far as I'm aware *merge* is only used as a noun in the context of source control.

However, as Barrie points out, the OED does list *merge* as a noun that means

> an act or instance of merging; a merger.

So it seems that *merge* is used in this way outside of source control.

I have also found 1 hit in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=merge.%5Bn*%5D&r=) for *merge* as a noun, although that looks like a mistake. I couldn't find any hits at the BNC.

I think if you use *merge* to mean *merger*, outside of source control, you will be understood, but it isn't widely done.

Comment: The online OED has an entry for _merge_ as a noun, defining it as ‘an act or instance of merging; a merger.’ There are supporting citations from 1806, 1905, 1935 and 1989.

Comment: I guess the usage of merge as noun in the source control context has made it seem more natural to me than it should. I'll shy away from it in writing then.

Comment: @wds I've updated my answer

Comment: The OED is wrong  :)  There is **one place** that "Merge" is commonly used as a noun: in computer programming.  If you have two pieces of code, and you merge them, the result is spoken of as **"a merge"** by programmers. So, you could refer to some speficic file (say) as a "merge" (noun).  Thus for example "Don't use that file, use this merge here - no wait, use the merge me and Steve made."

Comment: @wds Just to make sure we're all on the same page here, it is perfectly fine to use *merge* in writing if what you are writing about *is* source control. In fact using *merger* instead would be plain wrong.

Comment: In the US *merge* is also used as a noun to refer to the place where traffic merges, as defined [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merge?rdfrom=Merge)

Comment: @Fattie Programmers and computer scientist tend to get things wrong in general, e.g. using kilo for 1024—what the hell were they thinking? Conclusion: they cannot force others to accept merge as a valid noun, therefore merger it is!

Comment: @klaar quite right, and they still haven't fixed that in all the years since this QA appeared  :)